# Erode is too slow - Opencv

Tags: c++, performance, opencv

I'm applying an **erode** operation to a `Mat`, but it's being extremely slow.

Since in OpenCV you can apply it by two different ways (using `morphologyEx` and using `erode`).

I'm measuring (approximately) how fast does it runs, but both them are being extremely slow!

The code for this part is:

```
    int morph_size = 20;
    Mat element = getStructuringElement( MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size( 2*morph_size + 1 , 2*morph_size +1), cv::Point( morph_size, morph_size ) );

    // morphologyEx(imgMascara, imgMascara, MORPH_ERODE, element );
finish_time5 = clock();

    erode( imgMascara, imgMascara, element );

finish_time6 = clock();
```

Where `imgMascara` is a `Mat`. Then, When I'm measuring the time since the start to `finish_time5` and `finish_time6`, I'm getting:

```
0.0198s
0.887s
```

Any idea about why does it takes too much time? (It happen for both the functions, `morphologyEx` and `erode`).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this a release build? I have seen debug builds on Visual Studio take 100 times as long as release builds on some image processing algorithms.

Comment: It's a debug build @drescherjm, then I'm going to try to execute it in release!

Comment: do you have to use such big sizes?

Comment: I've not @Micka, my image size is even smaller than HD.

Comment: your structuring element size has size 41... if you (can) reduce that size drastically, your code should be much faster.

Comment: Hmm I tried to reduce `morph_size` to 10, and it's quite faster! But then I cannot get my desired output =( Do you know another technique or something I can do to avoid this? @Micka

Comment: maybe you can try to downsample your input image (and the filter size, too) by factor 2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81408/discussion-between-btc-sources-and-micka).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the reason of the lentitude of the erode. There're three different reasons:

1. As @Micka said, **the kernel size** is big. The more I **reduce it, the more faster it becomes**.

However, I can't do this, because I need this kernel size. So I continued looking for another reason, and found out:

2. The kernel type (`MORPH_ELLIPSE`). If I change it to `MORPH_RECT` or `MORPH_CROSS`, it becomes **drastically** faster.

Since my app works great with all them, I just **changed it to `MORP_RECT`**.

3. Debug -> Release: As I as told by @drescherjm, I've configured my project to **run in release mode** (plus depencencies from debug libs to release ones), and it helped the performance too. Not so much as the second reason, but a nice shot.

Thank you all for your comments that helped me to find out these

Comment: I was wondering, what makes MORPH_ELLIPSE slow compared to other kernels?

Comment: It is non-separable, for instance a rect NxM can be run with two 1D passes Nx1 and 1xM. So the complexity is N+M per pixel, while for an ellipse, it is NxM per pixel. There are optimizations by using sliding windows, with theoretical lower complexity, but they suffer from heavy branch mis-prediction which makes them slower in my experience.